# PYQt for beginner

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to show the QMainwindow after QDialog.It shows the dialog when it is time to show the QMainWindow program. Does not execute. Help?

```python
#import QtData_Tree as DT  
import sys
import sqlite3
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QDialog,QApplication

class Welcom(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Welcom,self).__init__()
        loadUi("Welcom.ui",self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Welcom")
        
class Login(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Login,self).__init__()
        loadUi("Login.ui",self)
        #self.login_btn.clicked.connect(self.loaddata)
        self.password_input.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.back_btn.clicked.connect(goback)
        self.login_btn.clicked.connect(goDT)
        
class data_entery(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(data_entery,self).__init__()
        loadUi("QtData_Tree.ui",self)

def goDT():
    log=QtData_Tree()
    widget.addWidget(log)
    widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+2)

   
app=QApplication(sys.argv)   
welcom_win=Welcom()
widget=QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(welcom_win)
#widget.setFixedHeight(550)
#widget.setFixedWidth(450)
widget.show()
app.exec()
```

I created a new file for the QmainWindow it worked but i am having problem linking the two files/programs

Comment: What do you mean by "when it is time to show the QMainWindow"? I don't see any attempts in showing or switching to the main window, nor it's clear when that should ever happen. Also, it seems like you're following a YouTube tutorial (or somebody's code based on that) that is known to provide terrible suggestions; I strongly urge you to completely disregard it. Specifically, in this case, you should never attempt to add a QDialog or QMainWindow to a QStackedWidget.

Answer (score -1):

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

class Welcom(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Welcom, self).__init__(parent)
        loadUi("Welcom.ui", self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Welcome")
        self.show()  # Show the welcome dialog

class Login(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Login, self).__init__(parent)
        loadUi("Login.ui", self)
        self.password_input.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.back_btn.clicked.connect(self.goback)
        self.login_btn.clicked.connect(self.goDT)

    def goback(self):
        # Add logic to go back
        pass

    def goDT(self):
        self.accept()  # Close the login dialog

class DataEntry(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DataEntry, self).__init__(parent)
        loadUi("QtData_Tree.ui", self)

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    welcom_win = Welcom()

    if welcom_win.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
        login_win = Login()
        if login_win.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            main_win = DataEntry()
            main_win.show()
            sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answers, instead add at least a brief description of what you did in order that the OP will understand the reasoning behind your changes.